# Not return my result from viewModelScope.launch

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

android studio 3.6

I need to return object `Double`

snippet:

```
 private fun getFuelPriceValue(fuel: String, date: Date): Double? {
        var resultFuelPriceValue: Double? = null
        if (!checkDateNearestFuelPriceMap.keys.contains(date)) {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val resultFuelPriceEntity = loadFuelPriceEntity(date)
                checkDateNearestFuelPriceMap.put(date, resultFuelPriceEntity)
                resultFuelPriceValue =
                    DictionaryService.getFuelPriceValue(fuel, resultFuelPriceEntity!!)
            } // launch
        } else { // load price from local
            resultFuelPriceValue = DictionaryService.getFuelPriceValue(
                fuel, checkDateNearestFuelPriceMap.get(date)!!
            )
        }
        return resultFuelPriceValue
    }


suspend fun loadFuelPriceEntity(date: Date): FuelPrice? {
  // code here
}
```

When `checkDateNearestFuelPriceMap` contain date then execute **else** branch. And success return my object  `Double`.
But when checkDateNearestFuelPriceMap not contain date then execute  `loadFuelPriceEntity`. After it's success executed the result is Double. But it return null. The variable `resultFuelPriceValue` is always **null**

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the result. `launch` coroutine constructor launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread so your method `getFuelPriceValue` is returning almost immediately with a **null** value.

Comment: So I need to use to wait the result of coroutine?

Comment: You want to return a value so you have to wait for the coroutine to set it before returning, otherwise it will return immediately with whatever value `resultFuelPriceValue` has at that moment (**null** in this case). Instead of `launch` you could use `async-await` to suspend the thread until the coroutine is done and then you can return.